# How to make Ionic build help me

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting this **Error** :

```
Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.0.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png into C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png


:mergeDebugResources FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



 What went wrong:


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 29.464 secs

Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.0.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png into C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png

 Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.0.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png into C:\Users\vipin\Documents\GitHub\Applozic-Server\Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a plugin compilation issue. According to the Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin compilation in android, please go and  ensure that you have installed the following items through the Android SDK Manager:

- Android Support Library version 23 or greater
- Local Maven repository for Support Libraries (formerly Android Support Repository) version 20 or greater
- Google Play Services version 27 or greater
- Google Repository version 22 or greater

I think this would be help to solve your problem.

[Please read this for more information](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Ionic-Chat-Plugin/blob/master/plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/docs/INSTALLATION.md)